# Solve the problem $Ax = 0$ when $A$ has full rank.

Tags: least-squares, svd, regularization

Generally, the answers $x$ of this least square problem
$$Ax = 0$$
where $A = []_{m\times n}$ and $x = []_{n\times 1}$ are in the null space of $A$.

I know that people usually use the right-most vector as an approximate solution (a column vector that corresponds to the smallest singular value). However, if we recall another least square problem $||Ax - b||_2$, there is the technique called Tikhonov Regularization, i.e. solve the problem by using the following equation,
$$(A^TA + \lambda R^T R)x = A^Tb$$
where $R$ is a regularization matrix and $\lambda$ is a positive real value. This equation is usually used instead of pseudoinverse when the problem is ill-posed (the solution $x$ is highly sensitive to the data in $A$ or $b$).

My question is that if I am trying to minimize $||Ax||_2$, is there any technique that is similar to Tikhonov regularization?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: what do you mean for *null space doesn't exist*?  Observe that the null space is always non empty

Comment: The kernel **always** contains the zero vector.The solution is $x=0$.

Comment: I mean when all of its singular value is non-zero.

Comment: Well, except for the trivial solution x = 0.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Let me re-write my question again. Sorry for an ambiguity.

Comment: What is the 'right-most vector'? Are you asking how to find $\ker A$?

Comment: It sounds like you want to minimize $ \|Ax\|_2$ subject to the constraint that $\|x\|_2=1$.  The solution is given by the SVD. Why not just use the SVD?

Comment: @copper.hat by using svd $A$ can be decomposed to $A = U\Sigma V^T$. What I mean by right-most vector is the column vector in $V$ that corresponds to the lowest singular value. Sorry again, that was not clear.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you are asking?

Comment: @aofkrittin: You can certainly do that, but it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @littleO yes, that is the problem I am trying to solve. And yes, I can directly use SVD. But I wonder if there is any regularisation technique as in least square problem for ill-posed condition, i.e. Solving least square system by $(A^TA + \lambda R^TR)x = A^Tb$ where $R$ is a regularisation term.

Comment: @aofkrittin: You should add relevant detail/motivation to the question.

Comment: So your question is to find the smallest singular value and associated vectors by not using the full SVD? In that is the case, you might use a variant of the inverse iteration.

Comment: I edited the question again. Hope this help clarifying any confusion. Sorry.